# Best way to calculate optimal subnet masks for a range of IP addresses?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, tcpip

I thought I saw a tool like this once upon a time, but can't find it anymore...

Anyone know a tool that would take a free range of IP addresses (as in start / end) and calculate a set of submasks that match the given range **exactly**?

I'm specifically looking for a tool that does **not** comply to class subnetting. So, for example, given an IP range like:

```
10.0.1.255 - 10.0.2.255
```

The tool should be able to return with two masks to match the exact range:

```
10.0.1.255/32
10.0.2.0/24
```

Comment: Not sure about the /32 in your example. See http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4632.txt and "Host route". As I read it /32 and /31 are special cases.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: This isn't a shopping question...

Comment: @dunxd As it is written ("give me a tool that does X") it's a shopping question - Google is the answer, just ask for `subnet calculator`.  If rewritten to "How do I calculate the optimal subnet mask for `X`?" the answer would be covered by [the canonical IPv4 Subnetting question](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Comment: You mean if rewritten in almost exactly the same way as they phrased the question?  I still disagree that this is a shopping question.  It isn't asking for product recommendations - it is asking for the right tool to use. Fair enough that this is a dupe, but just closing the question like this chases new users off.

Comment: I don't see this as a shopping question. The reason behind the question is that Google does not provide a simple answer to this problem. Searching for something like @subnet calculator@ brings up CIDR and subnet calculators, but nothing with the described behavior (hence the question). I should have worded it clearer that I was looking for a solution that wouldn't be tied to A/B/C classes or single masks, which the resulting tools invariably are. Looking for a tool is a reasonable question, considering that calculating such cases by hand get be pretty laborious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This web tool works: http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/subnet-mask-calculator.php

See also http://www.subnet-calculator.com/